# Percentage usage by each processor in my machine

Tags: java, cpu-usage, jmx

I want to know the usage percentage used by each CPU on my machine.
Is there a Java code or a Windows command to allow me to know this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Sigar](https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home). The [getCpuPercList](http://www.hyperic.com/support/docs/sigar/org/hyperic/sigar/Sigar.html#getCpuPercList%28%29) method in the [Sigar](http://www.hyperic.com/support/docs/sigar/org/hyperic/sigar/Sigar.html) class will give you usage stats on each core.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice MX bean for this:

```
OperatingSystemMXBean.getSystemLoadAverage()
```

that gets the overall load average. You can then divide this by the number of CPUs for the average per-CPU load.

Comment: thanks but i don't to need the avarage,i want to monitor the exact usage by each core